# POST request on postman works on other machines but not mine

Tags: spring-boot, curl, postman, swagger

I created a very simple API server in springboot and deployed it in a remote host.
When I send a POST request I get:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND remote-host.com

The strange thing is that this POST request works fine on other machines but not mine.
Another thing is that when I send this request via swagger it works fine as well (from my machine).

I tried using postman from the web, tried sending the request with cURL, and nothing works.

I also deployed this API to multiple hosts and all of them have the same configs.
The API works for me only on 1 env.
For example:
`remote-host1.com` works for me.
but `remote-host2/3/4/5....` not working on my machine.

Postman is up-to-date and also tried to reinstall it, but it didn't fix this error.

Tried reinstalling Postman, and sending the request in various ways.

Comment: Are those the actual domain names you are using? Are your domains publicly available in DNS, or only in some internal DNS? Or are they only in the `hosts` file on each machine?

Comment: can you ping  remote-host.com from terminal ？